# Shared data from root instance

Tags: vue.js

In my root Vue instance I am defining an `isAdmin()` method that does an ajax request to an API endpoint and determines if the user is an administrator or not, I put this method there as a lot of child components need to know if the user is an administrator or not.

The issue that I am running in to is that when the component accesses the root element data `isAdmin` the value is still `false` (default) and since the property is in the root instance the component does not react to the change.

Which is the best way to tackle what I'm tryin to achieve? I am trying to avoid having each component making it's own API call to the same endpoint.

Root instance:

```
window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    isAdmin: false
  },

  created()
  {
    this.checkIfAdmin()
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * Check if the logged in User is an administrator.
     */
    checkIfAdmin()
    {
      axios.get('/api/auth/isAdmin')
           .then(({data}) => this.isAdmin = data)
    }
  }
});
```

And then on a children component:

```
mounted()
{
  if (this.$root.$data.isAdmin) {
    //Does not fire as `isAdmin` is still false at the time of parsing
    console.log('I am an admin!')
  }
},
```

Some of my components are not direct child.. ie.. grandchild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.$parent.isAdmin` should give you the desired result.

> Forgot to mention, some of my components are not direct child.. ie.. grandchild.

Ah, yes, you can use `this.$root.isAdmin` then.

Comment: Forgot to mention, some of my components are not direct child.. ie.. grandchild.

Comment: this.$root.isAdmin works and is reactive.. I didn't need the $data key.. Thanks

Comment: `window.App.isAdmin` and `App.isAdmin` will also work

Comment: Because `window.App = new Vue({` makes every method, property data and computed value available with `window.App[PROPERTY]`